# Connection MySQL with PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, macos, pdo

I started a new small project on MAC OS X Yosemite
and i have a problem to connect to MySQL with PDO in PHP 5.5.22 like this:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=LOYER;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

The first respond:

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

and the second :

```
Erreur : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Anyone got an idea ?

I already looked for the socket and nothing seems wrong.

Comment: Have you actually downloaded and installed the latest MySQL version available ? Yosemite don't come with MySQL...If you have MySQL installed already, go to System Preferences and check if MySQL server instance is started.

Comment: connection refused = mysql's not running. 'no such file' = socket file not where it's supposed to be.

Comment: If you have installed mysql try starting it

Comment: try to naviguate to http://localhost:3306/ if your browser says connection refused mysql isn't running on the standard port (or isnt running at all); if it tries to download a file or display some strange text, mysql is running.

Comment: I use MAMP so MySQL is running i can access PhpMyAdmin on localhost:3306

Comment: when i do php -i | grep pdo
i can see the line :
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /tmp/mysql.sock => /tmp/mysql.sock

but there is no file mysql.sock in /tmp
in MAMP the file is here : /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
how can i change the path ? like this :
 pdo_mysql.default_socket => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: Did you ever figure this out because I am having the same problem

Comment: Sorry, it was just a mistake from my side